# GoogleAppEngine : GenericScorer.search throws NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to search an index in my project. 
When i search with the 
searchText: ***semester:"S1 / 2016" AND status:Validated AND emp_id>0***
, I am getting the results properly.

When i search with the 
searchText: ***semester:"S1 / 2016" AND status:Validated AND emp_id>500*** , I am getting the below exception

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.GenericScorer.search(GenericScorer.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.searchForApp(LocalSearchService.java:584)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.search(LocalSearchService.java:534)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:541)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:484)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:461)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:493)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:490)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is my code where the search is performed:

```
public Results<ScoredDocument> retrieveDocuments(String searchText) {
    if (searchText.length() > 2000) {
        throw new InternalException(new Exception("Error - Too long query !!"),
        BaseValidationMessages.SEARCH_STRING_EXCEEDS_LIMIT);
    }
    QueryOptions options =QueryOptions.newBuilder().setOffset(0).setLimit(2)
                                        .setSortOptions(createSortOptions("emp_id", "asc")).build();
    Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build(searchText);
    IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("Beneficiaries").build();
    Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);
    return index.search(query);
}
```

Comment: Are you still able to trigger this error? Generally a NegativeArraySizeException in library code (such as GenericScorer) indicates an integer overflow bug. I'd suggest filing a bug with the GAE library if you can still replicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Appengine throws NegativeArraySizeException, if the offset passed to the index search is out range of the available results count.

For E.g, Consider that there 50 documents available in search Index for the given search Query Text, if the offset set in the search query options is more than 50, then it would throw NegativeArraySizeException on executing the search.

```
QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder().setOffset(**51**)
```

So Before setting offset, make sure the documents are available for the offset using the previous results.

First Query:

```
QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder().setOffset(0).setLimit(50);
IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("Beneficiaries").build();
Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);
Results<ScoredDocument>results = index.search(query);
```

If the results returned from the above query is equal to 50, then search for the Next Set;

```
QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder().setOffset(**51**)
```

if the results returned is less than 50, then we can assume that, there is no more results available to search for the offset > 50, then we can stop further searching.